# Erasing an element of a vector that uses const_iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

I have a vector of Car objects, declared as

```
vector<Car> vCars
```

In one of my functions, I need to erase the first element of the vector. Sounds simple enough right? The line that is throwing the error:

```
vCars.erase( vCars.begin() );
```

And the error:

```
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Car>::erase(std::vector<Car>::const_iterator) const'
```

I understand erase generally only takes an iterator for its parameter, and not a const_iterator. I've been looking for solutions or workarounds to the error, such as the erase-remove idiom, but from what I'm seeing, that only removes an element by value, when I need to be removing by position - and simply enough, just the element at the first position! (I know this is not good performance wise for a vector, but I am required to use a vector for this)

edit: To clarify the situation, the function the call is contained within is below:

```
    /// Removes the Car at the front of the garage without returning the instance.
    void Garage::pop() const {
        if ( !empty() ) {
          vCars.erase( vCars.begin() );
        }
    }
```

edit: And I now see where I went wrong. There were a lot of methods that were const and I just mindlessly made pop() a const method! Once I removed const, the problem was resolved. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem, I advise you to accept one of them. This is the SO way of saying "thanks". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> no matching function for call to 'std::vector::erase(std::vector::const_iterator) const'

implies that `vCars.begin()` yields a `const_iterator`, which in turn implies that `vCars` is a constant object or reference. You are not allowed to modify the vector through that reference. If the function needs to modify the vector, it cannot take a constant reference.

Note that in a member function declared as `const` the implicit `this` pointer is of type `T const *` (i.e. you cannot modify the object inside a const function). If this is your case, you will need to drop the `const` qualifier from the function.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) only works for `iterator`s, it also works for `const_iterator`s in C++11. after all, to call erase, you need a modifiable reference to the vector, and if you have that, you can always get a normal non-const `iterator` from a `const` one. That's the rationale behind why they changed the member to take a `const_iterator`.

The problem is, you only get a `const_iterator` back from `begin()` if the object you're calling it on is also `const` qualified - in this case, your `vCars`. This, in turn, means you can only call `const` qualified functions on it, which is what the compiler tries:

```
... call to 'std::vector::erase(std::vector::const_iterator) const'
                                                             ^^^^^
```

I think you agree that `erase` being `const` qualified wouldn't make sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your parameter "vCars" is a const reference to the vector. You can make it mutable via const_cast or change your function design.

Comment: I don't think that `const_cast` should even be suggested.